# Why are my houseplant gingers leaves curling?

Tags: leaves, ginger

I purchased a variegated ginger plant for 
indoors,two weeks ago.. the leaves curled up yesterday, and I’m not sure why..It sits in a bright window, no direct sunlight.I did fertilize it yesterday with a product called vine wine..I would appreciate any answers you could give. thank you

Comment: are you able to add a photo which shows both the plant and its pot please?